# Accidental ETH to BTC wallet

Tags: wallets

I accidentally sent ETH in YoBit to an BTC wallet at blockchain [five days ago] YoBit has opened a support file, but no response yet. Is there a way to recover the ETH that is out in the ether somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

No. Unfortunately there is not.

Ethereum is a trustless, and immutable ledger. If a transaction has sent Ether to a non-existant address then it is irrecoverable.

Bitcoin have a different address format to Ethereum, so one would assume that YoBit would do some checks before sending Ether to an invalid address.

The only people who can help you here are YoBit.

Comment: Tell me please this solution https://decentral.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/226952087-I-accidentally-sent-ETC-to-my-ETH-wallet-in-Jaxx-Vice-versa- doesn't work for my case?

Comment: YoBit returned my ETH!